# Run C# application without SQL Server Management Studio installed

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have create a simple login application using the C#.net.

I have created database `test` in which I have created table called as `login`.

Table: `Login` contains:

```
create table login
(
    name varchar(20),
    pass varchar(20) 
)
```

Here is the login button code which I have written in the C#.net:

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = null;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from login", con);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == dr[0].ToString() && textBox2.Text == dr[1].ToString())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                count = count + 0;
            }
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fail");
        }

    }
```

**Note**: The above example works fine for me if I installed the Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Management studio in a single machine.

**But**

I want to run the above application in the machine where only Visual Studio 2010 is installed not SQL Server Management Studio.

Is it possible?

Comment: ya it is possible..but both system should be in same network..that is the system where visualstudio installed can access system having sql server and in datasource give the systemname or ipaddress of the machine where sql server is installed

Comment: Yes it is possible.. you can always install both on different boxes.. Only you need is to provide the database server IP in your **connectionString**

Comment: @Sachu, Nope. The machine is not in network. It's single machine which contains only VS2010.

Comment: @MAK .. where is your Database?

Comment: @MAK then its not possible..how u will access the database..otherwise u should create a localdb which can move along with visualstudio

Comment: @Sachu, Yup! That's what I am asking. How to move db along with visualstudio?

Comment: There is no need for SSMS. Maybe you don't have the required data access components installed and installing SSMS naturally fixes that. Or do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, there is no need for the sql server to be in the same network, as long as OP has the address, the machine can be anywhere in the world

Comment: @MAK then its better to go with some thing like VistaDB, SQLite, Compact Edition of SQL Server, MS Access, Firebird

Comment: @Yohannes Obviously. Just trying to find out why there is talk about SSMS

Comment: why do you need visualstudio to run the app ?

Comment: By the way - that has to be one of the worst ways of trying to find out if a row exists in a table - [WHERE clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) and [Commands and Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953(v=vs.110).aspx) would be two good places to start to learn better ways. (Then, later you'll probably want to read up on why storing *passwords* is a bad idea, but won't give yet another link at the moment)

Comment: I do this all the time without SSMS installed.  You have a credential issue.  Your connection string is perfect.  Don't change.  Are you using the same user account on remote PC where it does and doesn't work.   The remote PC and local PC needs to be In the same user group and the account on remote and local PC need to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YourUserId;Password=YourPassword
```

Also  you have to instal .net framework on your local machine

Answer (score 0):

The SqlClient types that you are using (SqlConnection, SqlDataReader, and so on) are defined in System.Data.dll (you can see this by going to the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the assembly is documented just above the big 'Syntax' heading') which is part of the .NET Framework. So as long as you have .NET Framework installed on a machine, you do not need any additional dependencies such as Visual Studio or SSMS.